# How to get all windows close when you select 'Close All Windows' on the app's taskbar icon?

Tags: wpf, taskbar

So I've been doing research on this for quite a few weeks now, and haven't really come up with an answer on why this doesn't work properly... I've even researched JumpLists to see if this was what I was looking for, but also to no avail.  This problem relates to when you attempt to select 'Close All Windows' by right clicking an app's icon on the task bar...

For example, here is an EXTREMELY small and simple WPF application I wrote to demonstrate the problem I am having.  Here is the app's icon in the task bar with its choices on the context menu for it...

[contextmenutoolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDmpD.png)
I am selecting the choice 'Close all windows', for reference (the bottom one, with the X to the left of it).

This is a WPF application and here is the code for App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="CloseAllWindows.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         >
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here is App.xaml.cs, which launches the MainWindow.  It also sets the application's MainWindow property to the MainWindow that is instantiated.  It also sets ShutdownMode to be only when the main window is closed... I don't want the application to still run if the main window is closed and some secondary windows are left open.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CloseAllWindows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        { 
            ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
            var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CloseAllWindows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CloseAllWindows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="NewWindow" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And here is the code behind for it... which launches a secondary window when I click a button.  It is setting the parent window (Owner property) to the main window, like all the examples I've seen say it should be set, and then call Show() on it.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace CloseAllWindows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var childWindow = new ChildWindow {Owner = this};
            childWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the child window, ChildWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CloseAllWindows.ChildWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CloseAllWindows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ChildWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And it's corresponding code behind, ChildWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace CloseAllWindows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ChildWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ChildWindow : Window
    {
        public ChildWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, these classes do not do very much... it was the simplest example of code I could write that shows the problem I am having.  So the issue is, if I select Close all windows from the task bar context menu, it never closes all the windows.  Instead, it will close the one child window, and still leave the main window open.  Interestingly, I hear the windows dialogue chime when I do this, almost like its getting interrupted by something, but I have no idea what.

It also appears to act very randomly... if I spawn 20 windows, it will sometimes close 6 of the windows, then all of them... sometimes it will close a few windows one by one, then close the rest... sometimes it will close all child windows and leave only the main window open.  Needless to say, I am pretty baffled as to the behaviour since it doesn't seem to follow any noticeable pattern...  any help greatly appreciated!  And hopefully the example is good enough to explain what I am trying to get at....

Comment: I also just noticed now if I have a multiple of 4 child windows, clicking 'Close All Windows' will close all windows, including the main window... very strange behaviour.  Not sure if this is coincidence or not... lol

Comment: I am going to consider this closed... I believe no one else will attempt to answer it... I have found it works in WinForms, which is odd.. I will post another Stack Overflow question showing the WinForms code I did and the WPF code I did and ask what is missing with WPF (if anything)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could add an event that will close every window the event is implanted in. try this example:

step 1: add a class to your project call it whatever you want, I called it CloseWindowListener, add this code to your class:

```
public static class CloseWindowListener
{
    public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> ClosingWindows;

    public static void CloseWindows()
    {
        var CWindows = ClosingWindows;

        if (CWindows != null)
        {
            CWindows(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

step 2: Add the event handler to the window you desire to close when it is called.

```
public partial class TestWindow1 : Window
{
    public TestWindow1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CloseWindowListener.ClosingWindows += CloseWindowListener_ClosingWindows;
    }

    private void CloseWindowListener_ClosingWindows(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

step 3: simply call the event from your main window or where ever you want.

```
    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseWindowListener.CloseWindows();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure this will work for my particular application... I don't want to add a new UI element that the user will press to close all the windows (they can already do this by closing the main window).  I understand what your code is achieving, but it is invoked by directly invoking it through a new UI item and not the task bar 'Close All Windows', unless I am missing something, I am trying to capture 'Close All Windows' event, if any.  I also can't close the main window when I get an event that the child window closes.. that would be incorrect behaviour in my app.  Thanks!

Comment: this will only close the window you add the event handler onto... just don't add the handler to your mainwindow and it won't be closed....

Comment: The thing is, I want the main window to close along with all the child windows when the user does Close All Windows from the task bar in one go.  Does that make sense?  If you look at the screenshot image I attached to the question, maybe this might help explain what event I am grappling with?  The thing is, the results are sporadic, and I mentioned in a reply to my own question that it will only close all windows when i have exactly a multiple of 4 child windows open... something I just noticed today after playing with it some more.